# Proof verification sequence convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Does $a_n=\log(n)\sin(\frac{1}{n})$ converges?

Proof:

Let $u=\frac{1}{n}$ so at $n\to\infty$ ,$u\to 0$ and $$a_n=\log(\frac{1}{u})\sin(u)$$

=> $$a_n=-\log(u)\sin(u)$$ now i know  $|\log(n)|<|n|$  and $|\sin(n)|<1$ so

$$0<|a_n|<|u||\sin(u)|=|u|$$ so $$0<|a_n|<|u|$$ as $u-0$ and since the absolute value of the sequence goes to zero so does the sequence.

**Question**:Can i change variables at natural numbers who are not continuous?

**Question2**:Do i need to translate it into real valued functions and use the a theorem to coorelate functions and sequences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I interpreted your question as can you perform change of variables. Yes, you may.

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\log(n)\sin(1/n)&= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\log(n)}{n}\frac{\sin(1/n)}{1/n} \\
&=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\log(n)}{n}\\
&= 0
\end{align}

There is a flaw in your bound:

While $\log(n) \leq n$ for $n \geq 1$, for small values of $x$, we do have $|\log(x)| > x$.

Comment: So my proof is incorrect ? but there are not $n<1$

Comment: also how did u know the last limiti?

Comment: You can for instance use L'hopital. $u < 1$ right?

Comment: ooh yeah $u$ goes to 0 so i cant use the inequality? :'(

Comment: I think the bound is too loose, what you wrote is just $|a_n|\leq n$.

Answer (score 1):

This is different from your approach but may be easier, for $0 \leq x \leq 1$ we have (by the Taylor series) that $0 \leq \sin(x) \leq x$ so we have for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that $0 \leq \log(n) \sin(\frac{1}{n}) \leq \log(n)\frac{1}{n}$. The result should follow easily.